# Laravel delete method not working just skips over the delete()

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hi all i am struggling a lot with the following im having a problem where i have delete method running but it is just not doing anything not deleting anything.

[This is my html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKyKW.png)

[This is my role controller page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/przQb.png)

if anyone can assist please

Comment: please edit and  post your codes here, instead of screenshot

Comment: the problem is in your route mapping. Please edit your post with real code (no screenshot) and add your routes/api.php (or wherever you wrote the link to your controller)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the

> $role

not

> $role->id

And insert the route file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function destroy($id)
{
$role=Role::find($id);
$role->delete();

}
```